# Is there an function for ordening and finding if the value already exists in c++?

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I'm studying a bit of c++ while re-doing a old project and found some difficulty to sort a user made list and keep it away from select the same numbers within the list, for example, I select a range for 1 to nth, then how many of these numbers do I want to select, for example is i choose 1 to 25 and pick 15 from them, my code will output "12 3 5 11 15 5 4 4 8 15 6 6 2 13 2". Prints way out of order and with some numbers repeating itself, i want to find a way to print them in order and without repeating. I'm a little lost on it!

I've tried used the `list::sort()` but without any result.

**EDIT:** The full code:

```
int selectedNumbers, rounds, totalNumbers;
list<int> numbersList {totalNumbers};

int Calc(int totalNumbers, int selectedNumbers) 
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= totalNumbers; j++)
    {
        numbersList.push_back(j);
        while (j++ <= selectedNumbers)
        {
            int randomList = (rand() % selectedNumbers) + 1;
            cout << randomList << " ";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "How many numbers on the total? ";
    cin >> totalNumbers;
    cout << "Number of rounds: ";
    cin >> rounds;
    cout << "How many selected numbers?";
    cin >> selectedNumbers;

    for (int i = 1; i <= rounds; i++)
    {
        Calc(totalNumbers, selectedNumbers);
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The current output:

How many numbers on the total? `25`

How many selected numbers? `15`

```
12 3 5 11 15 5 4 4 8 15 6 6 2 13 2

12 11 3 13 7 7 10 3 4 8 8 7 12 9 6

3 7 12 4 10 8 3 5 11 10 9 7 3 4 4

15 7 2 9 14 3 15 8 13 13 5 9 7 5 14

2 6 6 13 4 2 11 3 5 14 12 1 6 10 11
```

Comment: 1) Please elaborate, on what the actual problem is. Currently, it's unclear what is the meaning of the 2nd number, even after multiple reading attempts. Since you just generate some numbers, based on it, print those numbers, and discard them. 2) "_I've tried used the list::sort() but without any result._" Clearly, you have gotten _some_ result. Please elaborate on why it doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: "I've tried used the list::sort() but without any result." What result you have got?

Comment: The actual code is a bit longer, the stackoverflow throwed out the formatation when i pasted it here. The problem is that i give some inputs for the range of the number, and then how many of those i want to select, then print them in a sorted way and without repeating them

Comment: The best way to do this is to have a list with all the numbers `1..25` in it. Then randomly shuffle the list. Pick the top `15` items then sort it then print.

Comment: Could you please paste the code to stackoverflow? Fix the warnings. If you cannot, just ignore them. We can fix the formatting for you. Without the code it's hard to understand what you want...

Comment: I've posted on pastebin the code, the formatation was messed up here, but if it wasnt a problem, i can paste here too

Comment: Okay. I had a look through your code, but I don't get what you try to achieve. Could you please edit your post and added some examples on what the code is supposed to do? Btw. press `Ctrl+K` to format selected text as code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip dude! My goal was to make a simple guessing game to use with friends as a "drinking lottery" for fun and to learn things, nothing too fancy. In the end i've added the output when i choosed numbers from 1 to 25 and then selected 15 from these five times.

Comment: So you want to pull 15 numbers randomly from the range 1 to 25 and then shuffle them again five times? Or you want to pull 15 numbers randomly from the range 1 to 25 five times?

Comment: pull 15 random numbers from 1 to 25 five times and show them in a ordinate way without repeating themselves each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, I didn't see sort() function.

sort() function of list will sort the elements in the ascending order. unique() function of list will remove the duplicate elements from the list.

Below is one small example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <list>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const std::list<int>& list)
{
    for (auto &i : list) {
        ostr << " " << i;
    }
    return ostr;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> list = {8,7,5,9,0,1,3,2,6,4,4,3};

    std::cout << "list before: " << list << "\n";
    list.sort();
    list.unique();
    std::cout << "list descending: " << list << "\n";
}
```

Output :

list before:      8 7 5 9 0 1 3 2 6 4 4 3
list descending:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: Hey thanks for the input! i've removed the sort on this code, i will try this way and see if it works!

Comment: It kinda worked the way i was hoping for, it still needs some adjusts but thank you!